# How we can do rsa key exchange for jenkins, remote server for scp(ec2)?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, rsa

Please guide how can i do RSA (private,public key) exchange for authentication for Jenkins build processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make passwordless authentication from Jenkins server user to Remote machine user.

- step 1: Generate Key_pair in Jenkins Server

  ```
  $ssh-keygen
  ```
- step 2: Create a `~/.ssh` directory on the Remote server and set the
  mode as 600
- step 3: Copy content of `~/.ssh/id-rsa.pub` on Jenkins server to
  `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- step 4: Try the below command from Jenkins Server

  ```
  $ssh remote_server_user@remote_server_ip
  ```